# Google App engine standard environment /_ah/upload/ is failing with HTTP 503

Tags: google-app-engine, java-8, blobstore

Our production App engine standard environment Java 8 application is facing error when uploading files. This used to work until yesterday but started seeing HTTP 503 error in response to https://.appspot.com/_ah/upload/<upload_key>

Is there any service down specific to _ah/upload ??

Our file upload process.

1. String uploadUrl = com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService().createUploadUrl(uploadCallBackUrl); // returns an upload url of the form https://.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6aRaNw4HRDt9eS1d6crhKjxyEZ6aPCUrBE-0O8MftAY5BMzRw3kZkkCsqq5MJLDBfhWdZlVTKdfKuxBuD3QZDgZsRbUlx6QTD-B6MbJfTslohO7vcbBQet2I3kVUC4qAPwDSMHuI3lW6fvfbdehpz1pLYA88vlepiWgpHYEXtG8tqx5_MI/ALBNUaYAAAAAYEHvj10qLujApjnqp16MCEdnZecmQh1F/
2. File upload from browser to the url returned in step#1

I know we are using blobstore api, but this is legacy application which used to successfully upload files until yesterday.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

**Update** Moments later the service is working normally again. This must be a blip internal to GCP.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is to check if Google set a deprecation date for usig Blobstore API and whether that date has been reached.